# Null space of linear differential operator

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $L\colon C^n(a,b) \to C(a,b)$ a linear differential operator in the form
$$L= \frac{d^n}{dx^n}+a_1(x)\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}+ \dotsb +a_{n-1}(x) \frac{d}{dx} +a_n(x),$$

where $a_j (x) $ are continuous functions in $(a,b)$ for $j=1,2,\dotsc,n$.

My text book says that the null space of $L$, i,e, those functions of class $C^n$ for which $L(f)=0$ ($0$ is the zero function), has dimension $n$, it seems logical, but I don't know how to prove it, maybe this space consist only of polynomials? Thank you.

Comment: The space does **not** consist only of polynomials.  For example, consider what happens with $L = \frac d{dx} - 1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution to $Lf=0$ can be restated as a linear system of order $1$ ODEs, as follows:

\begin{equation}\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
y_0'=y_1\\
y_1'=y_2\\
\dots\\
y_{n-1}'=-(a_1y_{n-1}+\dots+a_{n-1}y_1+a_ny_0)
\end{array}
\right.\end{equation}

where $y_0=f$. We may convert this system into matrix form; with $\mathbf{y}=(y_0,y_1,\dots,y_{n-1})$ we have that $\mathbf{y}'=Ay$, where

$$A=\pmatrix{
0&1&0&0&\dots&0\\
0&0&1&0&\dots&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
0&0&0&0&\dots&1\\
-a_n&-a_{n-1}&-a_{n-2}&-a_{n-1}&\dots&-a_1
}$$

(it's okay that the $a_i$ are functions rather than constants.)

Now, we may choose some $t\in(a,b)$ and use existence and uniqueness with initial conditions $y(t)=e_i$ for $i=1,2,\dots,n$ to obtain unique solutions $f_i$.

Do you think you can finish the proof? You need to show that they $(1)$ are linearly independent; and $(2)$ span the space of solutions.

**Hint:** For $(1)$, evaluate them at $t$. For $(2)$, use uniqueness.

Comment: I got it now, thank you!

Comment: Can you explain further what it means to evaluate the $f_i$ at $t$ to show linear independent and then how uniqueness is used to show span? I am failing to relate $f_i$ to the matrix above. Thank you very much!

Comment: @korone Your system of equations has been restated in matrix form as $y' = Ay$. Let $t\in (a,b)$ be fixed. For each $i$, consider the initial condition $y(t) = e_i$ (in vector form; for instance, because $y(t) = (y_0(t), y_1(t), \dots, y_{n-1}(t))$, the condition $y(t) = e_2$ would amount to $y(t) = (0,1,0,\dots, 0)$, that is $y_1(t) = 1$ and all other $y_i(t) = 0$). For each of these initial conditions, indexed by $i$, the existence and uniqueness theorem will produce a unique solution to our system that satisfies the initial conditions; I called that solution $f_i$.

Comment: If we let go of the matrix language restatement, each IVP with initial condition $y(t) = e_i$ corresponds to prescribing the value $1$ to the $(i-1)$-th derivative of $f$ (in $Lf = 0$) and $0$ to all others.